# Undefined reference in Windows with QT, QTcreator and mingw32

Tags: qt, reference, qt-creator, undefined, mingw32

I'm getting undefined reference when I build an application in Windows witn mingw32 (it does not happen in Linux). The application is divided in two parts:

1- A set of designer plugins with the PRO like:

> QT       += core gui sql
>
> CONFIG      += designer plugin debug_and_release
>
> TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget(impwidgetsplugin)
>
> TEMPLATE    = lib

This generates the files: libimpwidgetsplugin.a and impwidgetsplugin.dll in c:\ilri\crossimpact\

2- A set of plugins in a library that requires impwidgetsplugin with the PRO like:

> QT += core gui sql svg
>
> TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(impmainmodules) TEMPLATE = lib CONFIG +=
>   plugin
>
> win32:LIBS += -Lc:/ilri/crossimpact -limpwidgetsplugin
>
> ....

The problem is that I always get:

```
./release\plots.o:plots.cpp:(.text+0x13f5): undefined reference to `calcDialog::calcDialog(QWidget*)'
```

calcDialog is defined in impwidgetsplugin.

i can see the make parameters have that required library limpwidgetsplugin:

```
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl -shared -Wl,--out-implib,..\..\..\libimpmainmodules.a -o ..\..\..\impmainmodules.dll object_script.impmainmodules.Release -L"c:\Qt\2010.03\qt\lib" -Lc:/ilri/crossimpact -limpwidgetsplugin -lQtSvg4 -lQtSql4 -lQtGui4 -lQtCore4
```

Any idea how I need to configure the PRO so it properly links it?

Many thanks for any help.
Carlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have almost the same behavior as linux, by using `LIBS+=-Wl,-export-all-symbols` in the plugin .pro file.

But it looks like you didn't export the class properly with the macros [`Q_DECL_EXPORT` and `Q_DECL_IMPORT`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html).

Comment: Yes!! That was the problem!. Thank you very much.